# zend conversion between query and DB_Select

Tags: php, mysql, regex, zend-framework

so I'm using this program http://code.google.com/p/ecartcommerce/source/browse/library/Ecart/Db/Table/Select/Disassemble.php?edit=1 to generate a string that corresponds to the zend db select command for creating that query..

but the thing screws up when I use an IN() statement in WHERE

so suppose I have

```
"SELECT * FROM j WHERE id IN (1,2,3,5,6)";
```

and I convert this using that class,

when I inspected the output, it stripped out the parentheses between the numbers in the IN clause, so it became

`->where("id IN 1,2,3,4,5,6")`, while it's supposed to be `->where("id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6)")`

Anyone knows how to fix this?

I suspect it has something to do with the _addWhere method:

```
protected function _addWhere($where)
    {
        $result = '';

        $where = 'AND ' . $where;

        $replacement = true;
        while ($replacement) {

            $replacement = false;
            $parts = preg_split(
                '/(\(.+\)+)/U', $where, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE
            );

            foreach ($parts as $part) {
                if (!preg_match('/\(.+?\)/', $part)) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (strstr($part, ' AND ') || strstr($part, ' OR ')) {
                    continue;
                }
                $replacement = preg_replace('/^\s*\((.+)\)\s*$/', '$1', $part);
                $where = str_replace($part, $replacement, $where);
            }
        }

        $parts = preg_split(
            '/(\(.*\))/U', $where, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE
        );
        foreach ($parts as $part) {
            if (preg_match('/^\(.*\)$/', $part)) {
                $replacement = str_replace(
                    array('AND', 'OR'), array('AND--', 'OR--'), $part
                );
                $where = str_replace($part, $replacement, $where);
            }
        }
        $parts = preg_split(
            '/(AND|OR)\s/', $where, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE
        );

        $type = 'where';
        for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($parts) ; $i++) {
            if ('OR' == $parts[$i]) {
                $type = 'orWhere';
            } else {
                $type = 'where';
            }
//            $subQuery = str_replace('--', '', trim($parts[++$i],'() '));
            $subQuery = preg_replace('/^\s*\((.+)\)\s*$/', '$1', $parts[++$i]);
            $subQuery = str_replace('--', '', $subQuery);
            $result .= "\r\t" . "->{$type}(\""
                    . $this->_replaceLongTableName(trim($subQuery)) . '")';
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

It specifically screws up in the `$replacement = preg_replace('/^\s*\((.+)\)\s*$/', '$1', $part);` line...

Comment: you want to fix addWhere method?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To use IN parameter in where clause, try the following way

```
$i = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);

$select = $this->select()->from('table','*')->where('i = (?)',$i);
```

when the parameter for where is an **array**, Zend automatically splits by ","